# Access JavaScript object property using variable

Tags: javascript, object

Is there an easier way to access an object property in JavaScript using a variable?

Here's what doesn't work:

```
var element_id = this.data().element_type + 'id';
```

Here's how it does work, which seems convoluted.

```
var element_id;
if ( element_type == 'assignment' ) {
    element_id = this.data().assignmentid;
} else if ( element_type == 'question' ) {
    element_id = this.data().questionid;
} else {
    element_id = this.data().answerid;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
var element_id = this.data()[element_type + 'id'];
```

This is the alternative syntax to dot property access, which allows you to specify a string denoting the name of the property.

The reason your approach didn't work is because `this.data().element_type + 'id'` means *first* evaluate `this.data().element_type` and *then* add `'id'` to it.